# xcode 5: code signing identity list not complete

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

Just updated and used xcode 5 to to up a 2nd version of my app. But now the problem is on the code signing identity.

WHen I open up my old files from xcdoe 4.5, I see the full list of my identities there, but on this new project, there is only one developer identity listed. the rest (developer & distribution) identities are no where to be seen.

I tried to reinstall the provision file again, but still nothing happens.

Anyone facing the same problem and manged to solve it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In Xode5+**

1) firstly select the **provision profile**

2) than select the **code signing identity**

[image]

Comment: One would think with Apple's legendary user interface prowess, they would put the FIRST thing you need to choose ABOVE the SECOND thing you need to choose ;)

Answer (score 7):

It might be possible that you missed to configure the developer account in Xcode 5. In lasest Xcode 5 Apple had changed a provisional profile settings. To see full list of the provisional profile you have to confiture your developer account using Xcode.

Steps :

1. Select your Xcode project file.
2. Go to general tab.
3. You will see dropdown for the Team click on it & configure your developer account over here. Then after you will see all the provisional profiles in Build Settings.

[image]

Hope it works!!!

Comment: Works great for me.. But i have to change the tem to my account...+1

Answer (score 1):

I've had some issues with IOS 7 and Xcode 5. If I remember correctly it required me to regenerate the distribution profile per app. I also needed to update the device list since they are dependent on the IOS version. It's a one off task and once you are done it should behave as expected.