# iOS 7.0 No code signing identities found

Tags: ios, ios7, code-signing

- certificate is valid
- xcode 5
- iOS 7

> Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the
>   provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“iOS Team
>   Provisioning Profile: *”) were found. CodeSign error: code signing is
>   required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

Comment: I call this the apple code-signin nightmare, I always solve this by removing my certificates/profiles redownload them, then map the right profiles.

Comment: see my SO Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086395/xcode-5-code-signing-identity-list-not-complete/19086878#19086878

Comment: Restarting the Xcode helps.

Comment: Restarting Xcode works for me :)

Comment: Third restarting XCode

Comment: Restarting XCode and restarting Mac didn't helps.

Comment: One thing to ensure is that the private key is attached to the certificate.

Answer (score 68):

**For Certificate**

1. Revoke Previous Certificate.
2. Generate New Development Certificate.
3. Download Certificate.
4. Double Click to put in KeyChain.

**For Provisioning profile**

1. Create New or Edit existing Provisioning profile.
2. Download and install.

**For BundleIdentifier.**

1. com.yourcompanyName.Something (Put same as in AppId)

[image]

**CodeSigningIdentity.**

1. Select The Provisioning profile which you created.

[image]

Comment: Sometime reboot helps, It helped me after reboot of my Mac.

Comment: You should also check that there is a distribution provisioning profile with an App ID that matches the bundle identifier for the app. Once I got those to match, the submit dialog quit giving me that error.

Comment: Before re-generating the certificates I would suggest to make sure you have the private key of the certificate you are trying to use.

Comment: Any specific reason that why we should revoke the previous certificates ??

Answer (score 44):

My fix for this problem was:

Xcode > Preferences. In Accounts click on your Apple ID. Click View Details, click on your projects Provisioning Profile (I think this helps) and click the refresh button bottom left.

Answer (score 17):

Thought I would supplement other answers with my own personal experience on this.

Recently I had an issue whereby two targets would build, and two would fail with the following error:

> Code Sign error: No code signing identites found: No valid signing
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team
>   ID “XXXXXXXXXX” were found. CodeSign error: code signing is required
>   for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

This was despite having updated everything in Xcode and on the [iOS Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action).

The hint was that the team ID shown in the build failure message about was out of date.

Sure enough, opening Xcode's `project.pbxproj` file in a Text editor found the old team id:

```
D29A93A318AB96440099C177 = {
        DevelopmentTeam = XXXXXXXXXX;
};
```

Incidentally, to get your `project.pbxproj` file, select your `.xcodeproj` file and do show contents as shown here:

[image]

Searching on the target Id `D29A93A318AB96440099C177`, I could see that it matched one of the failing targets:

```
targets = (
    F5E8B19A16E64505006F22D4 /* MyTarget1 */,
    93DB2342183F737100BEA69F /* MyTarget2 */,
    D29A93A318AB96440099C177 /* MyTarget3 */,
    D200F4B518AB968A00F58C21 /* MyTarget4 */,
    F5E8B1C016E64505006F22D4 /* MyTarget5 */,
    589FB35119114DED003D9350 /* MyTarget6 */,
);
```

In this case, `MyTarget3`. To resolve, a simple text search replaced the old team Id with the new correct Id. Problem solved.

**To Summarise**, hopefully your situation will be resolved using the answers above rather than delving into the complexities of Xcode's project file. However, if it doesn't, and the error shows an invalid team ID, then it's worth checking to see if that team ID is still around.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Not sure if it was because of me or someone on my distributed team with their own profiles, certs, etc. I put it up to git auto merging the pbxproj file poorly one time. That DevelopmentTeam I noticed comes from the Team dropdown under the General tab in my project settings. Completely removing that line worked for me if you want the team to be set to None.

Comment: i have check it, my DevelopmentTeam is correct how i get the new one id? 
the certificate install have same DevelopmentTeam which is in it.
please help

Comment: Works like a Charm. Just replace the Id that's being shown in the error with the one above it.

Comment: In my case I had to click the "Fix" button in *Target -> General -> Identity*

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same problem in development. I solved it by

1. Go to XCode preferences, view details of the Apple ID, and delete the provisioning file that's complaining.
2. Go to the Keychain Access, and delete the development certificate that's related to the provisioning file you just deleted.
3. In Apple Member Center, download the development provisioning file you just deleted locally, double click the file to make sure it's appearing in XCode.
4. Download the development certificate you just deleted locally, and double click to make sure it appears in the Keychain Access.
5. It should be good to go now.

Comment: This answer needs to be higher on the page.

Answer (score 8):

I just had this problem with Jenkins.

The solution was to copy the certificate and paste it into the system keychain otherwise Jenkins couldn't read the certificate.

Answer (score 7):

You should not have to delete all profiles to fix this issue,

When looking at my device profiles in the Organizer I saw one of my profiles was not valid.
I then went to the [Developer Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles page](https://developer.apple.com/) and all profiles were active, green and looked good but when clicking edit on the one that showed as invalid on my device, I saw that the check box in the associated account was not checked even though Select All was checked. I checked the box to associate the profile with my certificate, downloaded the Profile and everything was fixed.

On your Profiles web page click "Edit"
[image: On your Profiles web page]

You might see that there is no associated certificate even though "Select All" is checked.
[image: Edit you profile![][1]]

Comment: I was about to delete all my provisioning profile and start from sketch, then i came across you answer.Perfect buddy.One whole day wasted due to this issue.Thanks a lot for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 4):

For me, setting Project → Targets/[Your project] → General → Team to "None" solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Having gone through a ridiculous amount of time trying to solve one of these, and I definitely can see where most of these answers could be correct in some cases, my situation was not all that uncommon.

I was trying to deploy to the app store to test with TestFlight. A previous developer, no longer part of the project or company, had created the IOS Distribution Certificate. What xcode was trying to tell me was that yes, the certificate was in the member center, but dude you totally can't use it because it's not yours. I didn't have the private key needed to sign with it and no amount of refreshes, restarts, revokes were going to help me. You need a developer and distribution certificate to upload to the app store.

The solution was to create a new production distribution certificate in the member center, using a new signing request from my keychain. This process is documented well and described while you create the cert online. Once done, refresh your account in xcode to download to your keychain and you will be golden. I hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 2):

it might sound strange but for me worked restarting my mac..i cant explain why and what happened but it works now. hope it will helps someone

Answer (score 2):

I reached this thread when I am using pure command line/jenkins build script and I don't want any single UI/RDP manually setup for the integration environment.

After a few hours try to solve exactly the same issue using jenkins.
The key is "security list-keychains -s <your_keychain_name>"

--- Long story ---
I use a script in jenkins to override per-project settings (provisioning profile and signing identities)
After upgrade to Xcode 7, I have to change the script add above "list-keychains" after "create-keychains"

[Updated script here](https://gist.github.com/sinofool/39dc371e95c799094f7b).

Answer (score 1):

you need not to delete all your profiles.I had same issue and fixed it by installing the missing certificates. You might forgot to install the required certificate for the provisioning profile you are using for code signing.

- make sure that you installed desired certificates(development/distribution) into keychain for the code-signing provision profile(development/distribution).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change Bundle Identifier: Project -> Targets/[Your project] -> General -> Bundle Identifier

If app was published at AppStore XCode doesn't allow create the application with the same bundle identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Targeting iOS 8 and 9 on Xcode 7. My development profile is fine, I got this error while archiving the app for uploading to the app store. Here's what I did:

Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Details. Beside iOS Distribution, click the "Reset" button. This will invalidate the distribution provisioning profile that you are using (because you reset the distribution certificate), so edit the profile to include the newly reset certificate.

Make sure to download both the new distribution certificate and the newly edited distribution provisioning profile. Restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your **certificate is connected with your private key**:

Open **Keychain access, login, Certificates**. Find the certificate inside the list and see if it is properly paired with your private key.

If certificate is not signed with private key, delete it, go to apple developer page and create new certificate. Sometimes it will be needed to revoke old. This new certificate will be now properly signed with your private key.

Now, when you have new certificate, recreate needed provisioning profiles that will include new certificate in creation process.

Note, when somebody from your team reset this certificate with his private key, this same problem can appear again during the refresh process. I am not sure, but it seems that every developer in team must have own certificate for distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this issue has different causes. :)

For my case, my account log in expired... I solved it by simply:

XCode -> Preferences -> Account -> Apple IDs
-> Select the related ID and renew the log in...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Issue navigator and check if `Signing Identity:` is present in your **Keychain Access**. If no, download `.cer` file and append it to the keychain.

Answer (score 0):

After Pulling hair for a long time,I finally found an issue.I've selected wrong certificate while creating Provisioning Profile,By selecting right one,It helped for me.In your case,If it is multiple then You have to try and select one by one to get this issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this ambiguous error, "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1", when I was setting up new Jenkins boxes for iOS builds with Xcode 7.3, OSX 10.11.4.

In my case I had several things right:
1.Yes I had added my certificates to the keychain, both Apple's root and the team's cert.
2.Yes I downloaded the correct provisioning profile via xcode preferences.
3.Yes it even built manually in xcode.

However, for jenkins, there was perhaps a caching issue on xcode. What worked was:
1.Exit the Xcode GUI.
2.Get back in, and run the build manually once. 
3.Only then will Xcode prompt to allow keychain access authorization. 
4.Jenkins has some settings that might be able to fix this, but my machines are secure, so I click 'always allow xcode to access the keychain'.

Answer (score 0):

With [fastlane](http://fastlane.tools/) installed, you can create and install an Development Certificate by

```
cert --development
sigh --development
```