# Code Sign error How to fix Team ID not found

Tags: ios, xcode

`Code Sign error: No matching provisioning profiles found: No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “NNNNNNNNN” were found.`

I have been beating my head about this for a while, I have followed all the docs and looked at a bunch of other question. What is the fix for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23559911/67824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have installed your certificate and your provisioning profile and your provisioning profile should have your certificate choosen.