# Xcode 5 provisional profile

Tags: ios, iphone

Currently i have client's developer certificate and provisional profile.According to xcode 5 provisional profiles are selected through signing in developer account. I don't have client developer id.In  code signing, developer certificate is showing from keycahin,but provisional profile is showing from my current account, how can i include provisonal profile of client to xcode. Thanks

Comment: Check your bundle id.

Comment: Clean your project and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your provisional profile is configure with new certificate, and you have old certificate and vice versa.

So just check that you have updated certificate, if someone revoked it.

And go through this [iOS 7.0 No code signing identities found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-codesigning-identities-found/19197760#19197760)

Comment: How to add client provisional profile to xcode5,is it possible in xcode 5?

Comment: double click on that will add.

Comment: You have Provisional profile certificate ... Given By Client ... jUst double click on it.... now you see it in Build Setting ...

Comment: open your X-Code and click on project Now you see on top right Build Setting.... click on it .... then ... Code signing there click on provisioing Profile ....select your provisioing profile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-codesigning-identities-found/19197760#19197760

Comment: I have two provisional profile, one which i created with my account and other one which client give.I have double clicked client profile,but not shown in build settings provisional profile