# How do I get back a deleted private key from keychain?

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, keychain, private-key

I accidently deleted a private key in keychain access and when I try to archive my app these two ! show up.

> No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e.
>   certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile
>   specified in your build settings (“My App”) were found. CodeSign
>   error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK
>   'iOS 7.1'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-codesigning-identities-found

Answer (score 1):

You can't re-create a deleted private key. Restore your keychain from backups if you have them. If not, you'll have to create a new private key.

Comment: How would he do that?