# Appcelerator Titanium: Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

This is driving me crazy, I have spent about 10 hours now deleting and regenerating Apple keys and provisioning profiles for my Appcelerator Titanium iPad app. I had this all working and compiling 1 year ago, then my Mac crashed and I had to reformat and start over.

I cannot get past this error: "Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings ('Okland Construction 2014') were found."

In the Apple developer center I created the necessary distribution profiles and installed those in my keychain, but I always get this error.

I just have no idea what is missing or wrong.

I already read this and following instructions, to no avail:

[iOS 7.0 No code signing identities found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-code-signing-identities-found)

I hope someone can help before I lose my sanity. 10 hours, 100+ attempts, restarts, deletes, regens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to deploy the application into the device,

In a couple of situations, this issue occurs.

1. When you haven't installed provisional profile and corresponding developer certificate in your machine.

   - You need to use the correct developer certificate and provisioning profile. Go to your keychain and check whether the developer certificate corresponding to your provisioning profile is installed.
   - If the developer certificate is not installed, you can either download the correct one from developer center or you need to create new developer certificate.
   - If you are creating a developer certificate, you need to request for a certificate from the authority, then upload the .certSigningRequest file to the developer center and generate your developer certificate. Then update your current provisioning profile also.
2. Run configuration for your project is not correct one.

   - In some cases, Titanium Studio does not reset your project configuration automatically. So you need to reset it manually. For that
   - Open your Titanium Studio, then open your project.
   - Right click on the project then select Run as -> Run configurations.. (see the image 1)

[image]

- Select the development certificate, provisioning profile and device in the next screen(see image 2).

[image]

- Click the run button followed by the apply button.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Anand: Thanks for the detailed response, but I'm still getting the same error. A few differences between yours and mine: My run configuration is "Titanium iOS Ad Hoc/Enterprise Distribution". This app is in fact for adhoc/enterprise distribution because that's what my account and license type is. Also, I only see a private key under Keychain Access->Keys, related to this app. Shouldn't I have a related Public Key? And how do I create that or where do I get it? And I am using SDK 7.1. Should I downgrade to 7.0.3?

Comment: So you are trying to provide a production build. I think the issue is with your developer profile itself. Try the following 1. Request a new developer certificate from your keychain, save it to the disk 2. Go to developer site, revoke your developer certificate 3. Create a new developer certificate. 4. Upload the saved certificate key to the developer certificate. 5. Download the developer certificate, delete the old one from your keychain and install the new one. 6. Update your provisional profile. Download it and install in your machine. 7. Follow option 2 in my answer.

Comment: Anand: Yes, I am trying to make a production build. The code hasn't changed in the past year, I just need to update the cert/profile before it expires in a few weeks. Your recommendation sounds great but I am extremely nervous about *revoking* my developer cert. Won't that disable all deployed instances of my app out there? That would be catastrophic. I revoked a cert last year when I didn't understand the ramifications and suddenly there were a hundred employees of my customer that could no longer use their app. Please help me understand the ramifications. Thanks!

Comment: Also: Why is it necessary to revoke a cert? I would have thought all I need to do is delete certs/profiles from my Mac, then link up to the right one on Apple, even if there are multiple on Apple.

Answer (score 1):

My app failed to compile after following the instructions in the selected answer.
I found the above answer was correct after I did the following.

1. Open the xcode project in {app-root-directory}/build/iphone/{app-name}.xcodeproj
2. Checked the identity. Xcode advised that I had no private key for the developer certificate I was using.
3. Revoked and reissue the developer certificate within Xcode.
4. Deleted all my old named developer certificates within keychain access app.
5. Downloaded and installed a new developer certificate from developer.apple.com
6. Created, downloaded and installed a new provisioning profile for the app.
7. Find out the new uuid for the new provisioning profile for the app.
8. Followed the instructions in the selected answer above.
9. It now compiles.

Installing, deploying and distributing on Android is much easier ... I really prefer IOS devices but I now develop for Android first largely because of the hurdles put in place by the Apple Certificate system.

Comment: If you already have a Mac that compiles you can copy the account information from one Mac to another. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW15