# Titanium Studio on Mac : iPhone not listed

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying hard to build my titanium project on a Mac and run it on a connected iPhone 5S. For this, I have followed the steps here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Deploying_to_iOS_devices-section-27595262_DeployingtoiOSdevices-Apple%27sDeveloperprogram

The last thing I was able to do was to install the .mobileprovisionfile so that it got listed under XCode > Provisioning Profiles.

I'm now trying to run the project on the iphone, but I can't select the iphone as target in Titanium studio. When I hover the option "iOS Device", there is no sublist, not even an arrow indicating that there should be a sublist. So I can't select neither the iPhone nor the iTunes Sync like in the image in the documentation.

Additionally, the status of the provisioning profile I installed shows up as "Valid sign identity not found" in XCode.

Are those issues related?

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277122/appcelerator-titanium-code-sign-error-no-codesigning-identities-found/24278380#24278380.

Comment: Do you happen to only have the 3.4.0 SDK installed? I removed all older versions when 3.4.0 came out and all of the new devices disappeared. I then reinstalled 3.3.0 (Using Help/Install Titanium SDK...) and they came back.