# Xcode, archive from new mac with old developer profile

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

I have an Xcode app for iOS stored in github. I had some problems with my macbook and had to send it to store to fix it, but they formatted it.

Installing all back was no problem, but now I want to archive a new version of my app so I can have it on app store, but I cannot sing it.

I have imported my developer id, but still cannot archive it. I'm adding some screen shots so you can see my problem.

Hope you can find what I'm missing.

**Accounts:**
[image: Accounts]

**Error:**
[image: Error]

**First message:**

[image: First message]

**Second message:**

[image: Second message]

Comment: Ok, so following https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-code-signing-identities-found  it seems to be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new mac does not have the certificate for the developer profile, so it can't sign the app.

1. Go into the ios developer center and revoke your current certificate.
2. Generate a new developer certificate following their instructions
3. Download and install new developer certificate.
4. Generate a new devloper provisioning profile using the new certificate.
5. Download and install the new provisioning profile.
6. Restart Xcode.