# iOS provisioning profile issue when running on devices but works for simulator

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I recently changed my mac on which Iam developing iOS apps .I am getting the below error when I try to run the code on the iOS device but works fine for Simulator .I will not be able to import the developer profile from my old MAC as it is restored .

"No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“abcd”) were found.  Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center".

please provide me with clear steps to resolve this

Comment: export your old Mac keychain cer or private key that you are used for current provisioning profile .12 file and add this in to you new Mac keychain.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-code-signing-identities-found).
There is a lot of tips, let us know if none of them fix your issue, so we could try something else.

Answer (score -3):

here i can describe steps how to fix this hope that will be helpful.

- Go to your old mac `Keychain`--> find the developer cer that you are using for your `provisional profile`.
- Right click on that--> choose export and save **.12** as file.
- Expand it and right click on private Key --> choose export and save as a **.12** file.
- Copy both file and send this both file in to your new mac. and double click on it. That will be display in to you new mac keychain with key.
- Now try to select currect provisional profile in to you Xcode and run in to device. how that will he fix your issue.