# Xcode error: no provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity matching the bundle identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to run an iOS app on my iPhone in xCode. The app is essentially a third party keyboard for iOS, and it was made by a group of friends. They have added me as 'developer' in iTunes connect. When I try to run the app on my iPhone I get the following error:

> No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e.
>   certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier
>   “com.nameofteam.nameofapp.nameofapp-keyboard” were found. Xcode can
>   attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and
>   provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with
>   signing identities and provisioning profiles.

When I click on 'Fix Issue', it says:

> An App ID with Identifier "com.nameofteam.nameofapp.nameofapp-keyboard" is not available. Please enter a different string.

Comment: Please See This Link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-code-signing-identities-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Xcode is very particular about the name you give your App ID in the member center. Having the correct bundle identifier is not enough. You must use the specific format shown below for Xcode to "see" your App ID.

@romrom's solution of deleting the App ID and having Xcode create a new one was a clue. Unfortunately it was a nonstarter for me since my App ID was used by a Store app and therefore could not be deleted.

However, I discovered through some experimentation that I could solve the problem by manually editing the exiting App ID. It turns out that Xcode is really picky about the name of the ID, and not just the bundle ID.

For a typical bundle ID such as com.mycompany.appname, the App ID name must be in this format:

```
XC com mycompany appname
```

a name in any other format won't be seen by Xcode.

**How to check if you're affected / How to Fix**

1. Log in to the Member Center.
2. Click on "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".
3. One the left-hand navigation bar, click on "App IDs".
4. Locate the App ID with your bundle identifier.
5. If that App ID doesn't have the correct name format (as shown above), click on it then click the Edit button.
6. Change the name and click Done.
7. Enjoy the reduction in stress and anger.

P.S. There are some related problems if you're using Xcode 7.3 in which it won't automatically create proper distribution profiles for you, even if you fix the name as I mentioned above. The solution is to downgrade to 7.2.1 or 7.3 Beta or use a tool like fastlane/sigh.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you want to make sure your bundle identifier is **exactly the same** as the one on iTunes connect otherwise,

since you seem to have the source code it appears the bundle id you are trying to use is already in use, try a different **unique** identifier.

Also make sure you have your Apple ID connected to Xcode, it can be added in the accounts section of Xcode preferences. You may also need to create a self signing certificate in keychain access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Add your Apple ID to Accounts preferences in Xcode.
2. Go to General tab in Project and choose your team name from the Team pop-up menu.
3. Below the Team pop-up menu, click Fix Issue.

Comment: 2 days back, I was getting same issue, fixed this way only but now i can see this solution.

Answer (score 0):

as stupid as it sounds - make sure your **Provisioning Profile** is set correctly in the "*Build Settings*" tab, under "*Code Signing*" section, and that it matches the **Code Signing Identity** certificates.

In my case, I had the **Ad-Hoc dist** & **Release** provisioning profiles set correctly, but the the DEBUG was set to Automatic.