# Build Error in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to build a sample in codenameone, when i try to generate ios build i'm getting error like "Build Error" in codenameone-build server under builds. not understood why i'm getting this.

here is the Error Log what i got

```
Executing: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version Result is Xcode 7.3.1
Build version 7D1014
Xcode version line matching pattern: Xcode 7.3.1
Executing: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version Result is Xcode 7.3.1
Build version 7D1014
Build version 7D1014
Xcode version line matching pattern: Xcode 7.3.1
Executing: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version Result is Xcode 7.3.1
Build version 7D1014
Xcode version line matching pattern: Xcode 7.3.1
Executing: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version Result is Xcode 7.3.1
Build version 7D1014
Xcode version line matching pattern: Xcode 7.3.1
Executing: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dretrolambda.inputDir=/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4791690017772302908xxx/classes -Dretrolambda.classpath=/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4791690017772302908xxx/classes:/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/temp7148120558546354889.jar -Dretrolambda.outputDir=/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4791690017772302908xxx/classes_retrolamda -Dretrolambda.bytecodeVersion=49 -Dretrolambda.defaultMethods=true -jar /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/temp5509752908315778415.jar Retrolambda 2.5.1
00:00  INFO: Bytecode version: 49 (Java 5)
00:00  INFO: Default methods:  true
00:00  INFO: Input directory:  /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4791690017772302908xxx/classes
00:00  INFO: Output directory: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4791690017772302908xxx/classes_retrolamda
00:00  INFO: Classpath:        [/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4791690017772302908xxx/classes, /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/temp7148120558546354889.jar]
00:00  INFO: Included files:   all
00:00  INFO: Agent enabled:    false

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Failed xcodebuild step
```

if anyone have idea about this please help me..

sorry for my poor English..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: This isn't the full error text. Post a link to it.

Comment: sorry for late reply @Diamond.. i think i found error,i added to the question please check it..

Comment: i'm unable to sort it ..so i added error to the above question so could you tell me the solution for this please?

Comment: I don't see the link to the full error log in the question.

Comment: here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1j1lf1mu1q6d1r/LogFile.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The error in your log is here :

```
Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: 
No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (â€œMyApplication IOS_DEVELOPMENT Profileâ€) were found.
```

I indicate that your certificate linked to your provisionning profile (MyApplication IOS_DEVELOPMENT) is **invalid or inexistant.**
You can create a new provisionning profile with a new certificate or get back your exisiting certificate on itunes connect an add it in your CN1 settings.

Comment: I tried with new certificate also but again it showing same error only..

Comment: @tyson Did your provisioning profile was created with this new certificate ?

Comment: Take a look at this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-code-signing-identities-found 
Maybe it will help you

Comment: I have tried like above and now i changed from Development to adhoc.. 
now i'm getting the result like "Archive Succeeded "  but  "Export Failed".
here is the link for log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5t2rkfk9d9m1bu/newLogFile.txt?dl=0